# Side and Bottom Navigation Issue When Porting Kotlin MainActivity to Java

Tags: java, android, kotlin, navigation

Long story short I am new to the Android environment and bit off more than I can chew trying to learn Android and Kotlin.  I created my UI controllers in Kotlin and made use of the Google sample code to perform the fragment navigation.  After completing this, I found it to be much more efficient for myself to program my backend all in Java.  Not wanting to deal with two languages in the same application, I successfully ported all my UI Controllers from Kotlin to Java.  However, I am stuck on my MainActivity class.  Below is the Kotlin version, the two XML layout files, and my attempt at the Java version of MainActivity.

The confusion is regarding the two method calls setupBottomNavMenu() and setupNavigation Menu() in onCreate().

Class BottomNavigationView does not seem to have a method setupWithNavController(NavController navController) as in Kotlin.  The closest I can find is setupWithNavController(BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView, NavController navController).  If I choose this, and comment out the call to setupNavigation Menu(), the application works in portrait mode, but crashes when I tilt my phone (landscape mode).

Class NavigationView also does not offer a method which takes a single parameter of type NavController as in the Kotlin version.  Again I chose a similar method setupWithNavController(NavigationView navigationView, NavController navController), but then my app crashes upon start up.

Can someone shed some light on this for me?  I am spinning my wheels at this moment trying to understand what is going on.

My Gradle imports for navigation are:

```
def nav_version = "2.1.0-alpha03"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version" // For Kotlin use navigation-fragment-ktx
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version" // For Kotlin use navigation-ui-ktx
```

XML Layout Portrait & Landscape

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar" />

<fragment
        android:id="@+id/my_nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/my_nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer_menu" />
```

MainActivity.kt

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

private lateinit var appBarConfiguration : AppBarConfiguration

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    val host: NavHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.my_nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment? ?: return

    // Set up Action Bar
    val navController = host.navController

    //Create AppBarConfiguration with the correct top-level destinations
    val drawerLayout : DrawerLayout? = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(R.id.home_dest),
        drawerLayout)

    //set up bottom navigation (in portrait mode)
    setupBottomNavMenu(navController)

    //set up side navigation menu (in landscape mode)
    setupNavigationMenu(navController)

    //configure action bar for popping back on the stack.
    setupActionBar(navController, appBarConfiguration)
}

private fun setupBottomNavMenu(navController: NavController)
{
    val bottomNav = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_nav_view)
    bottomNav?.setupWithNavController(navController)
}

private fun setupNavigationMenu(navController: NavController)
{
    // In split screen mode, you can drag this view out from the left
    // This does NOT modify the actionbar
    val sideNavView = findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.nav_view)
    sideNavView?.setupWithNavController(navController)
}

private fun setupActionBar(navController: NavController, appBarConfig : AppBarConfiguration)
{
    // This allows NavigationUI to decide what label to show in the action bar
    // By using appBarConfig, it will also determine whether to
    // show the up arrow or drawer menu icon
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfig)
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean
{
    // Allows NavigationUI to support proper up navigation or the drawer layout
    // drawer menu, depending on the situation
    return findNavController(R.id.my_nav_host_fragment).navigateUp(appBarConfiguration)
}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import static androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController;
import static androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.setupWithNavController;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;
private NavController navController;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private Toolbar toolbar;

public MainActivity()
{
    //do nothing
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.my_nav_host_fragment);

    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph())
            .setDrawerLayout(drawerLayout)
            .build();

    //set up bottom navigation (in portrait mode)
    setupBottomNavMenu(navController);

    //set up side navigation menu (in landscape mode)
    setupNavigationMenu(navController);

    //configure action bar for popping back on the stack.
    setupActionBar(navController, appBarConfiguration);
}

private void setupBottomNavMenu(NavController navController)
{
    BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_view);
    setupWithNavController(bottomNav, navController);
}

private void setupNavigationMenu(NavController navController)
{
    // In split screen mode, you can drag this view out from the left
    // This does NOT modify the actionbar

    NavigationView sideNavView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    setupWithNavController(sideNavView, navController);
}

private void setupActionBar(NavController navController, AppBarConfiguration appBarConfig)
{
    // This allows NavigationUI to decide what label to show in the action bar
    // By using appBarConfig, it will also determine whether to
    // show the up arrow or drawer menu icon

    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp()
{
    // Allows NavigationUI to support proper up navigation or the drawer layout
    // drawer menu, depending on the situation
    return findNavController(findViewById(R.id.my_nav_host_fragment)).navigateUp();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?.` syntax is the [elvis operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) that only runs the following expression if the object is not null.

Therefore a call such as `bottomNav?.setupWithNavController(navController)` is two parts: an elvis operator and a [Kotlin extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions) (a static method that appears as if it was a method on another class).

The equivalent Java code would need to do both of those things to be equivalent:

```
if (bottomNav != null) {
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNav, navController);
}
```

(The choice on whether to use `import static androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.setupWithNavController;` or just use the static method directly is more of a matter of style - both work)